# Illegal character sequence \p' in string literal

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

When executing the following code:

```
string query = 'select id from ClientData__c';
string Point05 = '%\\file-01\projects\Internal Audit\Internal Audit 
Team\FY18\SOX\Testing%';

query += ' WHERE Point05__c LIKE \'' + Point05 + '\'';

List<ClientData__c> clientData = database.query(query);
```

I get the following error:

Line: 2, Column: 18
Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '%\file-01\projects\Internal Audit\Internal Audit Team\FY18\SOX\Testing%'. Illegal character sequence \p' in string literal.

Comment: This is not a regex problem. You need to tell us whnch programming language this code si in - [edit] the tags please - to get competent help; but basically, every backslash needs to be doubled. Many Windows programmers prefer to use Unix-style forward slashes instead of backslashes; this should work around the problem transparently.

Comment: Why is this tagged regex?

Comment: What language, C# ?

Comment: Sorry everyone. This is Salesforce Apex Code.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash (`\`) is used normally as an escape character. Just like you used in `query` line to escape single quote (`'`).

Here, in order to use in your string, you need to double backslash to escape the line backslash. Just change to:

```
string Point05 = '%\\\\file-01\\projects\\Internal Audit\\Internal Audit Team\\FY18\\SOX\\Testing%';
```

---

You may find its use [here](https://way2java.com/java-introduction/backslash-in-java/).